# SwiftUI View Model State, the view doesn't update

Tags: swiftui, observableobject

Here is a simple representation of what I'm trying to do. I need to have a view updated when values change in a class stored inside a published var. This `ContentView` should be updated when `Items` is updated in the `ItemManager` stored in the state of the `ContentViewViewModel`.

The `ContentView` with the ForEach well display the `Item` stored in the array, but if I store the array of `Item` in the `ContentViewState`  the view is updated correctly so why can't I move the data and logic attach to it in a subclass?

```
struct ContentView: View {
    @ObservedObject private var viewModel = ContentViewViewModel()
    
    var body: some View {
        VStack {
            ForEach(viewModel.state.itemManager.items, id: \.id) { item in
                Text(item.value)
            }
            
            Button("Add Item") {
                viewModel.triggerAddButton()
            }
        }
    }
}

class ContentViewViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    @Published var state = ContentViewState()
    
    func triggerAddButton() {
        state.itemManager.addItem()
    }
}

struct ContentViewState {
    let itemManager = ItemManager()
}

class ItemManager: ObservableObject {
    @Published var items: [Item] = [Item("Item 1"), Item("Item 2")]
    
    func addItem() {
        items.append(.init("NewItem"))
    }
}

struct Item: Identifiable {
    var id: UUID
    var value: String
    
    init(_ value: String) {
        self.value = value
        self.id = UUID()
    }
}
```

Comment: There is too much indirection here for no particular good reason. I would simplify this by removing MyState and and putting a Publisher of [String] directly on your view model, then feed that the Strings from whatever source of truth you have. ItemManager is really just an implementation detail.

Comment: All `ItemManager` need to be wrapped with `@ObservedObject` or switch it to a `struct`

Comment: Also have a look at this link, it gives you some good examples of how to manage data in your app using `ObservableObject`: 
[Managing model data in your app](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/managing-model-data-in-your-app). In essence, you have your code structure back to front. Also note that **nesting** ObservedObjects is not a good idea.

Answer (score 0):

`ForEach` is not a for loop, you can't use indices you need to make a struct that is `Identifiable` with an `id`, eg

```
struct Item: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    var text = ""
}
```

`StateObject` is for when you want to do something asynchronous like networking or use a Combine pipeline, in your case `State` is enough:

```
struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var items: [Item] = [Item(text: "Item 1")]
    
    func addItem() {
        items.append("NewItem")
    }
```

Or

```
struct Content {
    var items: [Item] = [Item(text: "Item 1")]
    
    mutating func addItem() {
        items.append("NewItem")
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {

    @State private var content = Content()
```

Comment: You're right my exemple was confusing I've updated it, actually the ItemManager could be much complex with networking, but the main question is why does the view doesn't update if I move the `[Item]` from the `State` to a subclass I store in the `State`?

Comment: You need to use structs instead of classes in Swift